# @font-face not working in IE, Firefox

Tags: fonts, font-face, windows-server

I'm using @font-face generated from Font Squirrel in a .NET application. The font renders great locally. But when publishing the application it only works in Chrome on the server, not IE/Firefox. I'm using all latest versions.

I've tried messing with the .htaccess file & adding .otf in the Mime types of the server but am still having issues.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Do you have any code to show?

Comment: `@font-face {
    font-family: 'AsapRegular';
    src: url('fonts/Asap-Regular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('fonts/Asap-Regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/Asap-Regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/Asap-Regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('fonts/Asap-Regular-webfont.svg#AsapItalic') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that when publishing the .NET application through Visual Studio it was not moving 12/16 of the font files to the server. After I added them manually all was working just fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is the format I use for Font-Face if this helps:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'headings';
    src: url('../fonts/headings.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/headings.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../fonts/headings.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/headings.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/headings.svg#headings') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my code:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'AsapRegular';
src: url('fonts/Asap-Regular-webfont.eot');
src: url('fonts/Asap-Regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('fonts/Asap-Regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('fonts/Asap-Regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('fonts/Asap-Regular-webfont.svg#AsapItalic') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. When I published the application through Visual Studio it did not pass 12/16 of the font files created by the font generator. So I physically put the files on the Windows server.

Everything is right as rain now.